# How to identify sql query is executed or not?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$sql='SELECT sender 
      FROM messages 
      WHERE message_id = :message_id';
$sender_result = $db->query($sql, array(':message_id'=>$message_id));
$sender = $sender_result->fetch();
```

I use this to execute above sql. How can I use `$sender` in the `If`.

Comment: I would help if you'd specify which type of object the `$db` variable is.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @ Berry Langerak : $db is database connection.                                     `$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->dbhost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname;`  `$this->db = new \PDO($dsn, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpwd);`

Comment: @ ilanco: yes, I add answer becoz I cannot answer my own question within 8 hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($sender[0]))){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using TRY-CATCH as:

```
try {
   $sql='SELECT sender 
      FROM messages 
      WHERE message_id = :message_id';
   $sender_result = $db->query($sql, array(':message_id'=>$message_id));
   $sender = $sender_result->fetch();

} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    // handle exception by using your own logic
    echo "An Error occured!"; //a custom error message
    your_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way you could test

```
$query = $DB->query(".....");

if($query) // will return true if succefull else it will return false
{
// code here
}
```